# django class based views for all categories with all entires

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I have tried this for a couple of hours, and looked at alot of documentation, but I cant get it right. I dont think I'll see a solution to this anytime soon, so maybe someone could see what is wrong?

I want a view to show all my categories and all my connected entries to those categories.

I have tried to follow this example: [django class-based-views topic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering)

But I get this error: tuple index out of range

My model:

```
STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('d', 'Draft'),
    ('p', 'Published'),
    ('w', 'Whitdrawn'),
)

class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    use_for_related_fields = True
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(PublishedManager, self).get_query_set().filter(status='p')

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    slug = models.SlugField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, default='d', choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    published = PublishedManager()

class Entry(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    slug = models.SlugField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, default='d', choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    published = PublishedManager()
```

My urls

```
#View for all categories and all connected entries
url(r'^blog/$', AllCategories.as_view()),
#View for one category - and all the connected entries
url(r'^blog/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', CategoryList.as_view()),
```

My views

```
class AllCategories(ListView):
    context_object_name = "category_list"
    queryset = Category.published.all()

class CategoryList(ListView):

    template_name = 'blog/category_and_connected_entries.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.category = get_object_or_404(Category, self=self.kwargs['slug'])
        return Entry.published.filter(category=self.category)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(CategoryList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add in the category
        context['category'] = self.category
        return context
```

Any help is much appreciated!

**Edit:**

Added my custom manager.
I only have problems not showing unpublised entires in my template for listing **all** my categories and **all** their connected entires like:

- Category 1

  - Published entry 1
  - Published entry 3
- Category 2

  - Published entry 7
  - Published entry 9

I use this for loop getting the connected entires, but it also list the unpublised entires:

{% for entry in category.entry_set.all %}

Comment: sorry I go sleep now mate but I only just notice you did have listview doing correct query so problem is likely your template code which can easy fix.  I check tomorrow for you or someone else can helping.

Comment: For now I do {% if entry.status == "p" %} in my template, but I think it is better getting a correct queryset of all publised entries instead, I just don't know how I would get that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use _set.all, my code:

```
views.py
class Categories(models.Model):
    model = Category
    template_name = "#..."
    paginate_by = #...

template
Categories list:
{% for category in object_list %}
    Name: {{ category }}
    {% for entry in category.entry_set.all|slice:":2" %}
        {{ entry }}
    {% empty %}
       None
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yes. Ended up with something like this.

Answer (score 1):

You get this mistake because the `self.args` which is a tuple of all the positional arguments is empty since you have not specified a group in your urls and you are trying to get the first element of an empty tuple(`self.args[0]`)

Change your url to:
`url(r'^blog/(\w+)/$', CategoryList.as_view())`,
in order to be able to capture the category using `self.args[0]`

Copying from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering):

> The key part to making this work is that when
>   class-based views are called, various useful things are stored on
>   self; as well as the request (self.request) this includes the
>   positional (self.args) and name-based (self.kwargs) arguments captured
>   according to the URLconf.

Apart from this i don't see any other mistake in your code.

Comment: Yes, that fixed it. Now my page for /blog/category_slug/ works. I get a list with all the connected entries.


But what do I do, if I want listing of **all** my categories? And on the same page, list all the entries connected to each category?

like

   <ul>
    <li>Category 1
       <li>Entry 1</li>
       <li>Entry4</li>
    </ul></li>
    <li>Category 2
       <li>Entry 8</li>
    </ul></li>
   </ul>

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment if you just wanting to show all category with related entry then all you need to do is fetch all category with

```
def query_set(self):
    return Category.objects.all()
```

Then in your template just loop over the categories and nested loop for entries

```
{% for category in object_list %}
    <ul>
        <li>{{ category.name }}</li>
        {% for entry in category.entry_set.all %}
            <li>{{ entry }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Wow, I have been thinking way to complicated! Thank you!

Comment: Now, a new problem. How can I use my custom manager with this? I have a manager called "PublishedManager", and I have "published = PublishedManager()" on my model. How can I use this manager in my template?

Comment: Category.published.all()....take a look at models and advanced models sections of the django book for more info

Comment: Yes, I have queryset = Package.published.all() in my view, but when I do: {% for entry in category.entry_set.all %} in my template, I still get a list of unpublised entries (I use the same manager on my entry model and Category model)

Comment: post the code for your model manager...if it is quite long then just edit into your question (if possbile)

Comment: I have edit my original question. Thank you all for your help so far! I have learn much already.