# django view - all categories and all entries

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to build a page with all of the model's categories and associated entries in one view. I followed tips from here [django class based views for all categories with all entires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519678/django-class-based-views-for-all-categories-with-all-entires) and here [Get all categories and items in category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419075/get-all-categories-and-items-in-category) but I still can't get it to work. Any ideas ?

-- models

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Feed(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.url
```

-- views

```
def category_page(request):
    object_list = Category.objects.all()
    context = {'object_list': object_list,}
    return render(request, 'category_page.html', context)
```

-- template category_page.html

```
{% block content %}
{% for category in object_list %}
    {{ category.name }}
    {% for entry in category.entry_set.all %}
        {{ category.name}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

I'm getting list of all categories displayed but no entries.

thanks
-M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
{% for entry in category.entry_set.all %}
    {{ category.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

should be

```
{% for entry in category.feed_set.all %}
    {{ entry.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

`{{ category.name}}` inside the forloop for `entries` is what is not displaying the correct name.

Also, what is `entry_set` ? If you are not specifying a `related_name`, you need to use the lower-case model name to get the related objects (`feed_set` in this case).

Something like this:

```
category.feed_set.all
```

Summing it up,

```
{% block content %}
{% for category in object_list %}
    {{ category.name }}
    {% for entry in category.feed_set.all %}
        {{ entry.name}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

You can read more on [related objects here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects)

Answer (score 0):

If this is your actual code, the problem is variable names in your template.

```
{% for category in object_list %}
    {{ category.name }}
    {% for entry in category.feed_set.all %}
        {{ entry.name}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Specifically, you refer to `entry_set`, but that's not the reverse name for the relationship since your model name is `Feed` rather than `Entry` and you haven't declared a non-default `related_name` argument.

Also, you're re-printing your category name instead of the name of the `Feed` instances.